# C++ not giving out of bounds error. Is there a way to force the compiler to check instead of undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

I am not getting any of bounds errors or segmentation fault, and I do see from people's comments that this is common. But is there a way to get the compiler to issue an error instead of opening my program to possible undefined behavior?

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 10

int main(void){

    int A[MAX] = {9, 3, 9, 3, 9, 3, 0, 0, 9, 3};
    int C[10];
    int B[MAX] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    C[i] = 0;

    //  increment count of buckets containing this digit accordingly
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)   C[A[i]] =  C[A[i]] + 1;

    //  count all count <= the current bucket to determine the correct index
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)    C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1];

    //  copy the correct array element to output array B and decrement C array accordingly
    for (int i = MAX-1; i >= 0; i--){
        B[C[A[i]]] = A[i];
        C[A[i]] = C[A[i]]-1;
    }

    std::cout << "\nSorted array = ";
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++)  std::cout << " " << B[i] << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ doesn't have any bound-checking. Indexing an array out of bounds leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in some cases can cause a crash or sometimes can [summon nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: There is no guarantee of diagnostic if you read outside of object   and you may end with smashed stack if you write beyond one with non-static lifespan. Or worse. It's not defined.

Answer (score -2):

Nobody promised you will get a `SegFault` every time you access the arrays out of bounds. Some data structures will give you an exception (std::vector, for example), if you try `v.at(MAX)`.

Still, your program usually has a lot of memory, and accessing `v[MAX]` is just accessing the next variable, like, it's very well known trick to do:

```
int a[10], b[10], c[10];

for( int i=0; i<30; i++) a[i] = 0;  // zero THEM ALL
```

To get a `SegFault` reliably you have to access NULL pointer or something **totally** out if your program memory area.

Comment: "To get a SegFault reliably you have to access NULL pointer" - huh? That's merely undefined behaviour too.

Comment: Truly, [dereferencing null pointers causing segfaults](https://rextester.com/QNOCD25068) is the most reliable of behaviours.

Comment: "`// zero THEM ALL`" - well, yeah, there is no guarantee that it will work, even if it currently works on all the major compilers. They are free to assume that there is no UB in the code and they are free to change the orders of the variables. You cannot rely that `int a[10], b[10], c[10];` will place `a` on the stack followed by `b` and `c`.